# Stereographic projection proof that is geometrical.

Tags: geometry

Given tangents $VP$ and $ZP$ on circle intersecting at $P$.
Prove: $YX=XW$

[image: Figure]

Heres what I do know. Obviously segments $ON, OV, OS$ are all congruent since they are just radii. I also know that $VP$ and $ZP$ are congruent since they are tangent lines intersecting. There is also an isosceles triangle $ONV$ since two of the sides are just radii which means angles $ONV$ and $NVO$ are congruent. I also know $OVZ$ is an isosceles triangle. Based off of all the information I have figured out I am not sure how to use it to show that $YX = XW$. Thoughts? Ideas? Solutions?

Comment: I know a proof using projective geometry. The core is the fact that the cross ratio of $(Z,V;P',N)=-1$ where $P'$ is the intersection of $NP$ with the circle. This cross ratio indicates a harmonic set, since $(Z,Z;V,V;N,P')$ are a quadrilateral set, as evidenced by the lines concurring in $P$. Stereographic projection preserves cross ratios, so $(Y,W;X,\infty)=-1$ hence $X$ is the midpoint between $Y$ and $W$. But this is building on *so* much theory which I wouldn't expect from most readers that I don't think you'd expect this as an answer.

Comment: I appreciate your response in helping me but I just want to show this with what I was given.

Comment: no ideas from anyone?

Comment: FYI: Given that the picture quality isn't great, you'd improve the problem substantially if you created a picture using something like Geogebra (of which there's a free Chrome app, btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ lie on $NW$ such that $XA \parallel PV,$
and $B$ lie on the extended line $NY$ such that $XB \parallel PZ,$
as in the diagram below.

[image]

Then $$\angle WAX = \angle WVP = \frac 12 \angle NOV = \angle AWX,$$
so $\Delta AXW$ is isoceles with $WX = AX.$
Also, $$\angle YBX = \angle NZP = \frac 12 \angle NOZ = \angle NYS = \angle BYX,$$ 
so $\Delta BXY$ is isoceles with $XY = BX.$
But $AX : PV = NX : NP = BX : PZ,$ and from $PV = PZ$ it then follows
that $AX = BX$ and therefore $WX = XY.$

No coordinates, no trigonometric functions, no inversions, just classical high school geometry.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for spotting the typo in the unedited version of the answer.

Comment: I think the only line of argument I am not sure on is $\angle NZP = \angle NYS$. Could you explain that.

Comment: @NickFreeman I used facts about the measure of an angle and the measure of the arc(s) it intercepts on a circle. For $\angle NZP,$ since the line $ZP$ is tangent to the circle, the angle equals half the angle of the intercepted arc from $N$ to $Z,$ that is, $\angle NZP = \frac 12 \angle NOZ.$ But $\angle NYS$ intercepts _two_ arcs (the short arc from $S$ to $Z$ and the arc from $N$ to $S$ not through $Z$) and therefore equals half the difference between the angles of those arcs; but that difference is $\pi - \angle SOZ = \angle NOZ.$

Comment: Alternatively, use the fact that $\Delta NOZ$ is isoceles. Then $\angle NZP = \frac{\pi}{2} - \angle NZO = \frac{\pi}{2} - \angle ZNO = \angle NYS.$ I just found the arc-length formulas easier to spot.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Last question. How does $PV = PZ \Rightarrow AX = BX$?

Comment: $AX:PV = BX:PZ$ and $PV = PZ$  together imply that $AX:PZ = BX:PZ,$ which implies $AX = BX.$

Comment: See I don't know what you mean when you put the colon between two segments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18122/discussion-between-david-k-and-nick-freeman).

Answer (score 2):

This is a coordinate-based proof. Choose (w.l.o.g.) the following coordinates for your points:

\begin{align*}
N&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} &
V&=\frac{1}{a^2+1}\begin{pmatrix}2a\\a^2-1\end{pmatrix}\\
S&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}&
Z&=\frac{1}{b^2+1}\begin{pmatrix}2b\\b^2-1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

This is using a rational parametrization of the unit circle, i.e. using the tangens of half the angle as the parameter. Then you have the tangents

$$2ax + (a^2-1)y = a^2+1\qquad 2bx + (b^2-1)y = b^2+1$$

which intersect in

$$P=\frac1{ab+1}\begin{pmatrix}a+b\\ab-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The stereographic projections of these points are

\begin{align*}
W&=\begin{pmatrix}2a\\-1\end{pmatrix} &
Y&=\begin{pmatrix}2b\\-1\end{pmatrix} &
X&=\begin{pmatrix}a+b\\-1\end{pmatrix} &
\end{align*}

So you can see that they are equidistant, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
\alpha = \angle SNY
\\\beta = \angle SNX
\\\gamma = \angle SNW = \angle OVN
\\\theta = \angle VOP = \angle ZOP
\\\phi= \angle NPO
$$
By considering the angle subtended by the chord VZ at N and O,
$$
\theta = \gamma - \alpha
$$
and by considering the triangle NPO,
$$
\phi = \pi - ((\pi - 2\gamma) + \theta + \beta) = \gamma + \alpha - \beta
$$
If the circle has radius $R$,
$$
OP = R\sec{\theta}
$$
Applying the sine rule to triangle NPO gives
$$
\frac{\sin{\beta}}{R\sec{\theta}} = \frac{\sin{\phi}}{R}
$$
and therefore
$$
\sin{\beta}\cos{(\gamma - \alpha)} = \sin{( \gamma + \alpha - \beta)}
$$
On expanding and simplifying this gives
$$
\tan{\beta} = \tfrac{1}{2}(\tan{\alpha} + \tan{\gamma})
$$
which is the required result, since
$$
SY = 2R\tan{\alpha}
\\SX = 2R\tan{\beta}
\\SW = 2R\tan{\gamma}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the inversion with pole $N$ that exchanges the circle and the line $SYXW$. This moves $Z,V$ to $Y,W$. Hence, $Z,Y,W,V$ are concyclic and the triangles $NZV$ and $NWY$ are similar.

Now look at the triangle $NZV$; let $M$ be the midpoint of $ZV$. $P$ is the intersection of the tangents drawn to the circumcircle at the vertices $Z,V$. It is well-known that the line $NP$ is the [symmedian](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Symmedian.shtml) in the triangle $NVZ$ that starts from the vertex $N$, so the lines $NM$ and $NX$ are symmetrical about the bisector of bisector of $\angle ZNV$.

Let $\varphi$ be the similitude that transforms the triangle $NZV$ to $NWY$. That transform can be obtained by applying a homothety with center $N$ and a reflection about the angle bisector of $\angle ZNV$. Then 
$$
\varphi(M) = \varphi(AM\cap ZV) = AP \cap YW = X.
$$
Since $M$ is the midpoint of $ZV$, the point $X=\varphi(M)$ is the midpoint of $\varphi(Z)\varphi(V)=WY$.